# Horned Mohawk looking insect. What is it?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Any ideas? I didn't know any other way to explain it.

I live in Indiana, USA if that helps.

Someone said it might be a "stink bug" but I'm not sure and not willing to find out!

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its definitely a True bug (Hemiptera), and based on its distinct pronotum and small head I'm guessing its a [Wheel bug (*Arilus cristatus*)](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/wheel_bug.htm). It is a common species that is also found in Indiana.

They are aggresive predators and are part of the family [Reduviidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduviidae) also known as Assassin bugs. Assassin bugs have a painful bite, and they inject a toxin when they stab their victim (so humans should watch out). This is not a part of the world I know well though, and there might be similar closely related species that I've missed.

Links:

- [Bug guide](http://bugguide.net/node/view/454)
- [Records in GBIF](http://www.gbif.org/species/2008593)
- [Univerity of Florida: Entomology & Nematology](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/wheel_bug.htm)

Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would have called it an assassin bug, but I guess you're more specific than that.

Comment: @user137 You are correct in the sense that it belongs to the family of Assassin bugs.

Comment: @ansarob Yes, they can have a nasty bite, and they inject a toxin when they stab a victim.

Comment: Right, this is definitely a wheel bug. Watch out for their bite!

Answer (score 3):

This does indeed look like a wheel bug ([*Arilus cristatus*](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/wheel_bug.htm)) as @fileunderwater indicates in his now 4-year-old [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/21834/16866).

I just wanted to add 2 bits of information:

1. **Range:** Most eastern US states, from New York to Florida, through parts of the midwest and central plains down through Texas, New Mexico and Arizona.

[image]

<sup>Source: [Bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/454/data)</sup>

- The University of Florida Entomology and Nematology [further claims](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/wheel_bug.htm):

  > It has been reported **from Rhode Island west to California**, and south to Texas and Florida. Blatchley (1926) included **Mexico and Guatemala** in its range. Wygodzinsky (1949) recognized four species of Arilus in this New World genus, but only cristatus occurs in the United States
- [This source](https://landscapeofus.com/garden/wheel-bug-arilus-cristatus/) provides an additional map (informally created from collected resources) that shows inclusion of California, Vermont, and Mexico in the wheekl bug's range..

-

2. Wheel bugs are [sexually dimorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_dimorphism), so do not be surprised if you see a noticeable gradation in size between specimens:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wheel_bugs_mating.jpg)</sup>

- I don't believe there is documented geographical size differences, so ranges in size would be due to age or sex.

---

<sup>Cited sources from quote (for convenience):</sup>

1. <sup>Blatchley WS. 1926. Heteroptera or true bugs of eastern North America, with especial reference to the faunas of Indiana and Florida. Nature Publishing Company, Indianapolis, IN. 1116 pp.</sup>
2. <sup>Wygodzinsky P. 1949. Elenco sistematico de los Reduviiformes Americanos. Univ. Nac. Tucuman, Inst. Med. Reg. (Pub. No. 473), Monograph No. 1: 1-102.</sup>