# What species is this grey insect with red antennae and mouthparts?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I’m very curious to know whether this is a type of ant or not, I only see 6 legs. Found in Tampa, Florida near Tarpon Springs.

[image: unknown insect]

[image: unknown insect]

[image: unknown insect]

Comment: Definitely not an ant.  Where was it?  I mean, it looks like it's in an old box with a strap...?  Is it rotten wood?  It looks like exterior lighting: was it outside buildings?

Comment: Also, how big is it?

Comment: See [Horned Mohawk looking insect. What is it?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/21833/16866) for more info.

Comment: It was approximately 1 inch long, no bigger than an American 25 cent piece. Located on a farm in Tarpon Springs. Found crawling on the wash racks for the horses.

Answer (score 2):

It's some type of Reduviidae, or assassin bug - possibly a juvenile wheel bug.  Here's a few pictures of Floridan assassin bugs I've found just browsing the net:

[image: Reduviidae]

Tagged as [unidentified Reduviidae from Tallahassee](http://www.floridanature.org/unidentified.asp?family=Reduviidae)

[image: Assassin bug]

Tagged as [assassin bug](https://extension.umd.edu/ipm/assassin-bugs-generalist-predatory-bug)

[image: Wheel Bug]

Tagged as a [Wheel Bug](https://marksteinmetz.photoshelter.com/image/I000072qGUns7.9I)

[image: Juvenile Wheel bug]

Tagged as a [wheel bug nymph](https://www.alamy.com/wheel-bug-arilus-cristatus-nymph-image225235564.html)

---

#### Bottom line:

Not an ant, for sure: it's almost certainly in the family of [Reduviidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduviidae), possibly the subspecies of *[Arilus cristatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_bug)*.